# Fuzzy Map for mapping errors of an API to Exceptions in Java

Tags: java, custom-data-type

I am working with an API, for which I would like to implement proper Error handling. The API is quite simple and works in a request/reply fashion.

It was designed in such a way, that every request is either acknowledged with a message including a keyword indicating success or a keyword indicating an Error followed by an error code and an error message.

While I can easily distinguish between successful and erroneous replies, identifying the errors and mapping them to exceptions is a bit tricky. While every error contains an error code, this code is not unique for the cause of the error.

```
ERR ABC: You have entered an invalid command "bla"
ERR XZ0: You have entered illegal characters "äöü"
ERR XZ0: Values must be between 1 and 4. 9 is invalid.
```

As you can see in my example, the last two errors have similar yet different causes while still carrying the same code. This makes it extremely uncomfortable to map the errors to Exceptions, since I can only identify the causes by combining the code and the message. As the API includes part of the error in its message, I will also have to isolate the part that shows the erroneous input. This input is not always in quotation marks, which makes it extra hard to identify. (◔_◔)

In order to perform reliable mapping, I am compiling a list of all possible error messages and codes. I then need to build something like a fuzzy map, which maps a given code and message to the closest available match available. (Most likely by simply searching for a substring match/calculating the levenshtein distance in the error message) Implementing this requires a couple of loops over the possible messages and codes and should not be too hard.

However, I would like my new FuzzyMap Data Type to implement java.util.Map. Am I violating any rules/properties of a Map by doing so? The resulting FuzzyMap will map multiple keys to the same value thus make it surjective. Will this result in any problems with my data type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need a special `FuzzyMap`. I would solve it by a simple `Map` which would map rules or regular expressions onto exception constructors. Something like:

```
Map<String, Function<String[], ? extends Exception> exceptionMappings = new HashMap<>();

exceptionMappings.put(
    "ERR ABC: You have entered an invalid command \\\"([^\\\"]*)\\\"",
    parameters -> new InvalidCommandException(parameters[0]));
```

You could then:

- check if the regex key matches your error message;
- if there's a match, extract all groups and put them into a string array (parameters);
- invoke the exception constructing function, passing the extracted parameters.

Quite straightforward and no need for anything fuzzy.

Comment: This is neat :D Thank you. The fuzziness is essentially eliminated by introducing the regex as a key in your example.